# SWIG Python default parameters

Tags: python, swig

Given the following C prototype function:

```
void my_function(POINTER *p);
```

How can one use SWIG to generate a Python wrapper that when calling:

`my_function()` ---> it will call `my_function(NULL);`

`my_function(None)` ---> it will call `my_function(NULL);`

`my_function(my_pointer)` ---> it will call `my_function(my_pointer);`

Answer (score 2):

You want SWIG to generate a default argument `NULL` for `p`. This is possible in either of the following two ways, Note that `None` is automatically passed as a `NULL` pointer.

#### 1. Using a "default" typemap ([SWIG doc](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn30))

Put the following typemap into your interface file before the declaration of `my_function`:

```
%typemap(default) POINTER *p {
  $1 = NULL;
}
```

#### 2. Specify a default argument in the function declaration ([SWIG doc](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_default_args))

You can show SWIG the following function declaration in the interface file instead:

```
void my_function(POINTER *p = NULL);
```

Even though this is not valid C, SWIG will know what to do. You can also put this after an `%include` statement to overwrite the function declaration in the C header file.

Comment: This is the answer. For completeness there's a third way too: use `%pythoncode` to add the extra code on the Python side of the interface rather than the C++ side.